# How to overwrite LD_FLAGS set by any bbclass in custom yocto recipe?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, yocto, dynamic-linking

In my yocto project, I have a application recipe that builds an executable from cpp source files for target arch.
It has also support to generate build for native target(Ubuntu 16.04), for which `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"` line is there in the recipe file. the executable is generated for native target just works fine on the same machine.
But the ldd command on the executable shows that the dynamic-loader(ld) used with the executable is not the default(`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`), it is using custom `ld-linux-x86-64.so` from `build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, However it is linked to the default loader. But if we run the same binary on different machine, this sysroot-uninative path will be unresolved which results the binary to not run on other machine of same architecture. running in different machine shows error "No such file or directory".

After detailed exploration I got to know that the `--dynamic-linker` (linker-flag)is set by `uninative.bbclass` in the `LD_FLAGS`. which is default inheriated in `poky/meta-poky/conf/distro/poky.conf`.
Removing that line from `poky/meta-poky/conf/distro/poky.conf` file resolves my issue but i don't know its side effects.

So anyone can suggest me, How we can overwrite the LD_FLAGS value in my recipe.bb file? so that I can remove the --dynamic-linker flags value or overwrite with default loader(`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For overwriting anything, you can use .bbappend file. Write your changes there